# My Perl variable to variable substitutions do not work

Tags: perl

I have a substitution to make in a Perl script, which I do not seem to get working. I have a string in a text file which has the form:

```
T+30H
```

The string T+30H has to be written in many files and has to change from file to file. It is two digits and sometimes three digits. First I define the variable:

```
my $wrffcr=qr{T+\d+H};
```

After reading the file containing the string, I have the following substitution command (starting with the file capture)

```
@scrptlines=<$NCLSCRPT>;
foreach $scrptlines (@scrptlines) {
$scrptlines =~ s/$wrffcr/T+$fcrange2[$jj]H/g;
}
```

$fcrange2[$jj] is defined and I confirm its value by printing its value just before the above 4 lines of code.

```
print "$fcrange2[$jj]\n";
```

When I run my script, nothing changes for this particular substitution. I suspect it is to do with the way I define the string to be substituted.
I will appreciate any assistance.
Zilore Mumba

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Watch out for the first `+` in `my $wrffcr=qr{T+\d+H};`. It'll make it match 1 or more `T`s, not `T` followed by a `+`. You probably want

```
my $wrffcr=qr{T\+\d+H};
```